# Sudden loss of 50 reputation points

Tags: support

My reputation points on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83509/jugal-shah) were 323  until yesterday, but when I logged in today there was a sudden loss of 50 rep points and my reputation was 273. I could not see any activity upvote, downvote or de-acceptance of any my previous answers.

Comment: I don't see any of your accounts having reputation anywhere near this, I see 317 on Stack Overflow...which account are you talking about?  You should *always* link to whatever doesn't look correct.

Comment: It is my StackOverflow account. It was 273 on 11 March and today I earned another 44 which makes it 317.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? :(

Comment: I see the down-vote automatons are at it again. I'm almost ashamed.

Comment: I can't speak for other downvotes, but I initially downvoted (changed to upvote after comments & edit) because the numbers didn't match your description. It would have been helpful if you'd mentioned this change was as-of yesterday, so reputation gained today could be ignored.

Comment: Usually people who ask this question are running "sock puppets" (aka fake accounts) to artificially inflate their reputation.  You share IPs with many other people.  I suggest that if you have friends/coworkers who share your IP and are upvoting your posts, that you avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case a user who votes up your content 5 times was removed.  We don't *currently* show this in your profile because the rep change is 0 on those votes as part of the deletion...we'll take a look at this being in the profile, but can't promise as it's a rather odd case data-wise and from a social standpoint.